# Convert.FromBase64String Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I try to do the following code :

```
byte[] arr= Convert.FromBase64String("1/50/Zoolz/Win-s9u0uco8ea0(11)/349.jpg")
```

I received the following error:

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

who can I solve it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You string looks like a path of a jpg file. What are you trying to convert?

Comment: I want to use it as a key by Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr).ToLower();

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh That doesn't make much sense. Could you explain in detail what are you actually trying to do (and not just how are you trying to do it).

Comment: To "solve" this problem, provide a valid Base64 string. `1/50/Zoolz/Win-s9u0uco8ea0(11)/349.jpg` is not a valid Base64 string. If you don't know what a Base64 string is, you probably shouldn't be using `Convert.FromBase64String`. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the base64string to the method rather passing it path first convert the image to base64string and then call method on that string.

*Converting Image to base64string*

```
 using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
      var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
      fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
      string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
 }
```

*Converting base64string to image*

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64String);
MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.FromBase64String` expects a base 64 coded string as parameter, not the name of a file containing something that is base 64 coded.

If the image file content is base 64 coded, you sould first of all read the file and then call `FromBase64String` on that content, as in:

```
string baseText = File.ReadAllText(<filename>);
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(baseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not employing a base 64 coded string, it is just an ordinary string. If you are trying to create a test, you may use the following code to convert a string to base64.

```
  string stringToBeEncoded = "some string";
  byte[] byteArray = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToBeEncoded);
  string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```